# Chrome extension content_script add html with onchange function, function is undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first try on creating a chrome extension and most stuff is already working out. Except for one thing.

I created a script that insert a SELECT the SELECT has a onchange that calls a function that is defined in my content script. But when the select onchange fires, the function that is calling is undefined.

Code samples:

manifest.js

```
{
"name": "Extra Filters",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["..."],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
]
```

}

content.js

```
function CreateSelect(index, options) {

    if(options == null) return;

    let html = `<select onchange='AddFilter(${index}, this)'>`;
    options.forEach(option => {
        html += `<option 
            value="${option}">
            ${option}
            </option>`;
    });

    html += `</select>`;

    return html;
}

function AddFilter(index, value) {
    console.log(index, value);
}
```

So when the select changes, I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: AddFilter is not defined

Comment: The HTML runs in the context of the page. You need to set `element.onchange` directly (or use addEventListener) so that it runs in the context of the content script.

Comment: Is that gonna change anything? The HTML is the same, the onchange function is the same. I tried with element.onchange, but same result.

Comment: Content scripts run in an isolated world so their functions aren't available in page context or html. You probably made a typo or maybe used element.onchange in the wrong place or didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page. Note that html won't be the same as you need to remove onchange from html.

Comment: I made no typo. When I execute the function in the extension JS, I get an log back. When I try to execute the function from the browser console tab, the function also doesn't exists. So I don't think the problem is with how the event is getting triggered, but how my function is defined in the extension. Like you said, the content script is isolated. Any tips?

Comment: I can't help without seeing the new code/[MCVE](/help/mcve). Also note that the console runs in page context so you need to switch its context to the extension using the context switcher in the toolbar of the console.

Comment: As far as I understand you: The current way is useless cause the code is isolated in the extension container. So the HTML will never be able to reach it. So I have to find another approach. So again, it doesn't matter how I attach the event to the element, its about how/where I should define the function to be executed.

Comment: `element.onchange` uses DOM directly, not via HTML, you call it in the content script directly and it runs in the content script and thus can access the functions of the content script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235258/discussion-between-niels-lucas-and-woxxom).